# Access VBA How to extract a text outside a [] from a String

Tags: vba, ms-access

In an Access Form I can enter values in a TextBox called LenD. Sometimes I need to check the input code in order to split standard text from a code. For instance:

noumnoum[codecode]

To obtain:

noumnoum

So that, I use this:

```
If InStr(1, Me!LenD, "[") Then
            Me!LenD = Left(Mid(Me!LenD, InStr(1, Me!LenD, "[") + 1, (InStr(1, Me!LenteD, "]")) - (InStr(1, Me!LenD, "[")) - 1), 50)
        Else
            Me!LenD = Left(Me!LenD, 50)
End If
```

But I just obtain the string inside the "[" "]". My aim would be to obtain the string that is on the left of the original String. Any idea on why it does not work?

Comment: Your code does locate the `[ ` and the `]` and take the string between, limited to 50 characters, why would you expect another behavior?

Comment: How should the code behave if "noumnoum" itself contains `[` or `]` ? If you are talking about computer code, surely there must be e.g. some escape rules for including symbols in string literals that must be taken into account. Otherwise, you have a fragile parser that will fail on some edge cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Split* and simplify this:

```
If Not IsNull(Me!LenD) Then
    Me!LenD = Left(Split(Me!LenD, "[")(0), 50)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim x as Long
 x = Instr(me!LenD,"[")
 If x > 0 then
     Me!LenD = Left(Me!lenD,x-1)
 Else
     me!LenD = Left(Me!LenD,50)
 End If
```

Comment: Add some textual information to your answer please. Otherwise it cannot be considered a good answer and may be deleted.

Comment: Go ahead, it's not like I'm getting paid for this.